# Identify the type of control selected on DiagramControl object

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using DiagramControl of devexpress tools. When I add shape, insert images and text field on it. How do I detect the type of control which is selected by user on its SelectionChanged event?
When I use diagramControl.Items array iterator

```
for (int iControlIndex = 0; iControlIndex < diagControl1.Items.Count; iControlIndex++)
{    
    (diagControl1.Items[iControlIndex] as DiagramImage)
}
```

if its DiagramImage then it works but if it is DiagramShape it gives exception.
I need to write something like switch case on shape item selected which gives Shape type in cases like its Shape or Image or Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just try something like this:

```
DiagramItem currentItem = diagControl1.Items[iControlIndex];

if (currentItem is DiagramShape)
{
     // Do whatever for DiagramShape
     (currentItem as DiagramShape).DoSomething();
}
else if (currentItem is DiagramConnector)
{
     // Do whatever for DiagramConnector)
     (currentItem as DiagramShape).DoSomething();
}
```